# PHP variable in MySQL query WHILE string breaks

Tags: php, mysql

Why can I not use a PHP string variable in a LIKE selector in a MySQL query?

```
$weekday = '%w%';
echo "$weekday"; 
$sql = "SELECT id FROM message_instance
            WHERE day LIKE $weekday";   
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
```

Gives me this error message:"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%w%' at line 2"

I have tried it with double quotes around the variable. Still get the error.

If I substitute in '%w%' instead of the variable it works fine.

I have used PHP variables in other queries without a problem. I just cannot understand this.

EDIT: Sorry I must have been even more tired than I thought I was. You are all right I posted a wrong query. I was trying everything to get this to work with a placeholder and I have no idea what I was doing wrong.

But I DID have a problem that I cannot get.

```
try
{date_default_timezone_set ("Pacific/Honolulu");
$daynum=array ("s","m","t","w","h","f","a");
$weekday = strftime("%w");
$weekday = $daynum [$weekday];
//$weekday = "w";
$weekday = '%' . $weekday . '%';
//$weekday = "%w%";
echo "$weekday"; 

$sql = "SELECT id FROM message_instance
            WHERE day LIKE :weekday";   

        $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->bindValue(':weekday', "$weekday");
        $s->execute();

$result = $s->fetch();

foreach ($result as $row)
{
    $messageids = array(
     'id' => $row['id']); //THIS IS THE ERROR LINE
}

print_r ($messageids);
exit()
```

and with single quotes I get it working in a variety of ways - sorry. I was really getting a different problem altogether which I still cannot fathom.

I have been using PREPARED statements and BIND for security and then recovering data in a very standardized way only in this instance I cannot get it to work.

I get back:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in C:\xampp\htdocs\...\gonogo.php on line 28
Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in C:\xampp\htdocs\...\gonogo.php on line 28
Array ( [id] => 1 )
```

I have used this fetch/foreach array combo in other places without problem. Just cannot see where this is going wrong. The array should contain 1, 4 and 5.

Comment: Since it's already answered, what are you trying to accomplish here ? i have a feeling you're doing it the wrong way, also this query is vulnerable to SQL injection !

Comment: I agree about the injection attacks. I always use prepared statements now. This was just a hacked around experiment in my early days on a local server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your field type is not integer (or number-based, for that matter), you need to encapsulate your inputs with quotes.

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM message_instance WHERE day LIKE '$weekday'";
```

---

But please, protect yourself from [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) and use [PDO's prepared statements feature](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the single quotes around `$weekday`:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM message_instance
        WHERE day LIKE '$weekday'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
$weekday = '%w%';
```

With:

```
$weekday = "'%w%'";
```

You need quotes around the wildcard when it is output.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this instead:

```
$weekday = 'w';
echo "$weekday"; 
$sql = "SELECT id FROM message_instance
        WHERE day LIKE '%$weekday%'";   
$result = $pdo->query($sql);`
```